# asp.net mvc javascript postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm mixing `asp.net` webforms and `asp.net-mvc`. To use webforms I've included

`routes.IgnoreRoute("Reports/{*pathInfo}");`

in the `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` method.

It seems to work just fine. But javascript postbacks on the `asp.net webform` pages don't work. Specifically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callMethod(methodName, methodArgument)

{

        alert('test1');

        document.getElementById("methodname").value=methodName;

        document.getElementById("methodargument").value=methodArgument;         

alert('test2');

document.forms[0].submit();

    }

</script>
```

doesn't work. Everything is fine until the `document.forms[0].submit();` call which appears to do nothing. If I completely disable the asp.net MVC route mapping then the above Javascript works just fine.

Comment: What's the value of the action attribute on the first form tag?

Comment: <form method="post" action="Billing.aspx?tenantId=0003-0140&amp;rentNum=0" id="ctl00_ctl00_basemasterform">

Billing.aspx is the current page

Comment: I updated my answer for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just completed a brand new sample project and was able to get this to work...  I created a folder in the root of my project called Reports and added the Billing.aspx page there.  I then added the code below to the default Index view within the Home folder as shown below.

**Global.asax**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Reports/{*pathInfo}");
```

**MVC Page Views\Home\Index.aspx**

```
<form method="post" action="../../Reports/Billing.aspx?tenantId=0003-0140&rentNum=0" id="myForm"> 
    <input type="text" id="sample" /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="callMethod();" value="send" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callMethod()
    {
        alert('test1');
        alert(document.getElementById("sample").value);
        alert('test2');
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

---

My guess is that even though your form's action is set to Billing.aspx, it is not looking for it in the correct folder.  Try adding "../../Reports/" in front of Billing.aspx to your form's action.  Since the Billing page is not in the same root as the MVC page, that is likely to not go anywhere on a post action...

Comment: I've included 

//ignore webforms files
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            
and 

routes.IgnoreRoute("Billing.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

and it didn't fix the issue